# Why are there only finitely many simplicial maps from one polyhedron to another?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex, triangulation

I don't understand why for two polyhedra $|X|$ and $|Y|$, there are finitely many choices of simplicial maps $$s: |X^m| \rightarrow |Y|$$ for some large enough $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Multiple sources say it "follows from the definition," but I don't see how it is that obvious. Is it because $s$ is linear, so it is determined by its effect on vertices, and since there are finitely many vertices in the polyhedron, there are finitely many ways $s$ can affect them? That seems too handwavey. Would anybody care to explain?

Comment: Instead of saying "multiple sources", please **cite** **one** source **explicitly** and then we can look at that and see what we think. If you are criticising or having doubts with the literature, then you must give the relevant references.

Comment: Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_map) writes, "Simplicial maps are determined by their effects on vertices. In particular, there are a finite number of simplicial maps between two given finite simplicial complexes."

Comment: Keep in mind you've noted that both simplicial complexes $X$ and $Y$ are finite! You got it exactly that there are finitely many vertices in $X$ and $Y$ so there's only finitely many ways to construct the map. You can consider $x_1,...,x_j$ to be the vertices of $X$ and $y_1,...,y_k$ to be the vertices of $Y$. How many maps are there from the set of vertices of $X$ to the set of vertices in $Y$? It's a finite number. Then the number of *simplicial* maps is less than that too since the list above was just arbitrary maps!

Comment: The Wikipedia reference doesn't say anything about "for large enough $m$". Where are you getting that bit from? (There are actually finitely many choices for every $m$.) This is why I was asking for a specific reference.